# ndash & mdash in Times New Roman broken in Debian 10

Tags: xetex, texlive, fontspec, times, debian

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
dash-dash, ndash--ndash, mdash---mdash
\end{document}
```

compiled with texlive xelatex yields the expected dashes under Debian 9 (stretch, current stable), but under Debian 10 (buster, current testing) the result is:

[image]

What the layer of the technology stack is broken?

Comment: inserting `[Ligatures=TeX]` does not change the result

Comment: file `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty` of Debian 10 contains the version info `\ProvidesExplPackage{fontspec}{2017/09/22}{2.6e}{...`

Comment: whereas Debian 9 has `{2017/02/12}{2.6}`

Comment: xelatex versions are `3.14159265-2.6-0.99998` (Debian 10) and `...99996` (Debian 9)

Comment: both of those are someway behind texlive texlive 2017 has `Package: fontspec 2017/11/09 v2.6g Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX`

Comment: and is the bug is fixed in `2.6g`?

Comment: lualatex under Debian 9: correct result. Under Debian 10 fails: `! Font \TU/lmr/m/n/12=[lmroman12-regular]:+tlig; at 12pt not loadable: metric d
ata not found or bad.`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle as a default it should at first load lmodern - but the error doesn't sounds good.

Comment: (now we are at lualatex) Yes. After three times hitting Enter, I get many exclamation marks and `! fontspec error: "font-not-found"` and `! The font "TimesNewRoman" cannot be found.` at `l.4 \setmainfont{Times New Roman}`

Comment: Yes, package `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` under Debian 10.

Comment: Sounds as if lualatex can't create its database. But this is a new question. Going back to xelatex: Can you add `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1` to your document and show the log-file?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jwuttke/956702c517d1766e94c1f4160c5010d0

Comment: You didn't add `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1`  (or not at the correct place, put it before \documentclass).

Comment: Indeed, I had put it after `\documentclass`. Now I put it before - and `test.log` is exactly the same.

Comment: back to my original question: if I knew what package is likely to cause the bug, then I could submit a bug report

Comment: The log should not be the same. Please show it again.

Comment: There is no bug in a package. It is a problem with your font. The log says `Font "Times New Roman" does not contain any OpenType 'Script' information.` which it shouldn't do. So we need the output of the font tracing to see which font is actually used.

Comment: indeed, my fault. Now the log is 50 lines longer: https://gist.github.com/jwuttke/c75d145a99f4af4cd2487292fec46315

Comment: xetex doesn't find the tec-file: `Font mapping 'tex-text.tec' for font  ... not found`. And the call to times looks very odd.  But I can't look now more, I have to go.